# GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Field new_test2 not found in log schema. Query cannot proceed! Derived Schema Fields:

Tags: parquet, amazon-athena, apache-hudi

there's a hudi table that is written as parquet file in s3, I ma trying to query it using athena, firstly it worked fine, then when I try to add a column and try to query it again I get this error:

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Field new_test2 not found in log schema. Query cannot proceed! Derived Schema Fields:
```

despite the fact that when I try to query the same table using spark.sql it works fine. I don't know why this is happening as far as I understand that athena can handle schema changes, so why it's mentioning that the col doesn't exist?
and also if I tried to alter the table to add the col, we get an error of duplicate col which means it can see it.
ps: this error happens in athena engine v3, but when I set athena to automatic it works fine.

Comment: Can you check if the table schema is updated in your Glue metastore? It can be a problem with the Hive sync task in your write job

Comment: @HusseinAwala it's updated, and still give me the error.